# aurio_touch---how to take input from avaudioplayer rather than mic

Tags: iphone, core-audio, avaudioplayer

aurio_touch sample is taking input from mic,but i want to take show frequency waves while playing sound files.
Is it possible through audio_touch,if yes then how?
please reply...